# Styling echarts - Cannot modify title color

Tags: ruby-on-rails, echarts

Looking to work with the below chart, but cannot get to change the title color to white and the axis and axis numbers to grey (or white). This should go above a dark background. Does anybody knows how to change the title color with echarts ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
              // based on prepared DOM, initialize echarts instance
              var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

              // specify chart configuration item and data
              var option = {
                  title: {
                      text: 'Total memebers of the club',
                      fontColor: 'white',
                      display: true,
                      position: 'bottom'

                  },
                  tooltip: {},
                  legend: {
                      data: ['Total member']
                  },
                  xAxis: {

                      data: ["11/2018", "12/2018", "01/2019", "02/2019", "03/2019", "04/2019"]
                  },
                  yAxis: {},
                  series: [{
                      itemStyle: {normal: {color: 'white'}},
                      name: 'Total',
                      type: 'bar',
                      data: [5, 384, 612, 2344, 4670, 9372]
                  }]
              };

              // use configuration item and data specified to show chart
              myChart.setOption(option);
          </script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Give this a try.  Add it under 'text:' like:

```
text: 'Total memebers of the club',
textStyle: {
    color: '#ed2d2e'
    }
```

Comment: works perfectly, thanks